# WCF domain-specific contract, service and DTO separation

Tags: wcf, dto, separation-of-concerns

We have multiple WCF services for different domains/scopes (application-specific data, users, management etc.). We automap entities to DTOs, but here I encounter the first design issues.

*How could, and should, we separate the services, contracts and DTOs?*

This is especially tricky if we would need different views on the same data - i.e. a user might be able to read the data for himself, but should not get any associated management-data since that is outside of his scope.

My initial approach would have been to put all the DTOs and contracts into a separate assembly for each domain, or rather each service (e.g. `CoreContracts`, `OrderContracts` etc.). This however makes separation of the different views on the same data much harder, especially if I don't want to add new services just to serve data for these views.

Example (omitting attributes):

```
public class UserDto
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public string Username {get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set}
  public string Address {get; set;}
  public bool ExampleManagementFlag {get; set;}
}
```

*This is just an example and not actually how this is implemented*

The `ExampleManagementFlag` is something that the user, for himself or services on behalf of the user, should not even see. I would therefore use a separate DTO for the user-side access, plus a separate contract and place that in a separate namespace/folder in the corresponding contracts assembly.

**But:** using separate contracts would make maintaining the WCF bindings a nightmare (multiple services, multiple environments to configure - i.e. each developer has a debugging-environment, we have a test-deployment environment and a production-deployment environment...) - on the other hand, putting everything into one large contract would yield ugly methods like `GetUser(id)` and `GetUserForUser(id)` etc.

...Another option, which I personally do not prefer (which the project currently uses...) would be to create a separate contract for each client-server relationship. So stuff like `OrderWebService.OrderWcfService`, `OrderWcfService.CoreWcfService`, `CoreWebService.CoreWcfService` - and let's not forget `CoreWcfService.OrderWcfService`...

Authorization is not so much an issue if we have separate methods and DTOs. I'd like to avoid returning the same DTO for all requests because that doesn't tell you which fields are applicable for which context - and it would pollute the business logic with authorization instead of mostly relying on resource based authorization (i.e. user could `Read` on `UserScope.User`, but not `Read` on `Superset.User` - or `ReadForUser` on `User` but not `ReadAll`).

I hope what I've written makes sense or helps to explain the problem I'm facing. I'm struggling to put this into comprehensive words.

*Edit* the current pattern we use in that project has also lead to literally copied DTOs all over the place, with the argument that it might need to diverge *some day*

Comment: do you use contract inheritance?

Comment: Generally, we don't use inheritance for something like that. We have a few use cases where inheritance makes sense but I didn't consider it to create subsets of the contracts etc. - and I'm not sure that's viable